# Https client (HttpsURLConnection) - вытащить body. Java

Tags: java, json, https

Здравствуйте. Для отсылки запросов по https протоколу, я использую следующий код:

```
public String HTTPSPost(String url, User entity) throws Exception {

    String body = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(entity);
    URL link = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) link.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
    OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(body.getBytes());

    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);


    StringBuffer responseObject = new StringBuffer();
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(inputLine);
        responseObject.append(inputLine);
    }

    String response = new ObjectMapper().readValue(inputStream, String.class);
}
```

В ответ мне может прийти как текст, так и json объект. В любом из этих случаев, мне нужно получать String body, но получать не так, как в приведенном коде, а при меньших ресурсных и временных затратах. То есть, если мне придет response размером в 2 Мб, то затратится очень много времени и ресурсов на распарсивание ответа, то есть на while, что для меня категорически не подходит. Мне нужно просто достать тело ответа. 
И еще один момент - ObjectMapper мапит json объект при передачи ссылки на класс этого объекта, но мне нужно получать этот json объект в виде текста, а я не понимаю как мне это сделать. Спасибо за любые ответы.